# Hatcher Theorem 3.26 - orientability

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds

I am reading Hatcher, the beginning of the chapter on Poincare duality. I am trying to understand how theorem 3.26 is deduced from lemma 3.27 and I must admit I find Hatcher's proof very esoteric.

Theorem: let $M$ be a closed connected $n$-manifold. Then: 
(a) If $M$ is $R$-orientable, then the map $H_n(M;R) \to H_n(M \mid x;R) \cong R$ is an isomorphism for all $x \in M$. 
(b) If $M$ is not $R$-orientable, then the map $H_n(M;R) \to H_n(M \mid x;R) \cong R$ is injective with image $\{ r \in R \mid 2r =0\}$ for all $x \in M$.

Lemma: under the same assumptions on $M$ as above, if $x \mapsto \alpha_x$ is a section of the covering space $M_R \to M$ then there is a unique class $\alpha \in H_n(M;R)$ whose image in $H_n(M \mid x;R)$ is $\alpha_x$ for all $x \in M$.

Hatcher defines the $R$-module $\Gamma_R(M)$ of sections of $M_R \to M$ and infers from the lemma that the map sending a class $\alpha \in H_n(M;R)$ to the section $x \mapsto \alpha_x$, where $\alpha_x$ is the image of $\alpha$ under the map $H_n(M;R) \to H_n(M \mid x;R)$, is an isomorphism. He then says that if $M$ is connected then each section is uniquely determined by its value at one point. He then says that the theorem "is apparent" from the earlier discussion of the structure of $M_R$.

I would be grateful if someone could spell out why it is so "apparent" that the theorem follows, and what features of the structure of $M_R$ are relevant. The main problem for me is that the lemma doesn't say anything about orientability, so I'm not sure how one can use it to prove the theorem.

Answer (score 4):

We know that $M_R$ is a disjoint union of the covering spaces $M_r$, which are isomorphic to the trivial cover $M$ if $r=-r$ and to $\widetilde{M}$ otherwise. Furthermore, $\widetilde{M}$ is homeomorphic to two copies of $M$ iff $M$ is orientable.

So, for (a) when $M$ is orientable, $M_R$ is a union of copies of $M$. Hence any section $\alpha_x$ is determined by its value at a single point and is just a homeomorphism from $M$ to the relevant component of $M_R$. The $R$-module of sections is thus isomorphic to $R$, so the isomorphism in 3.27 gives the result.

For (b) when $M$ is not orientable, $M_R$ is a union of copies of $M$ corresponding to the elements of $R$ with $r=-r$ along with copies of $\widetilde{M}$ corresponding to the other elements of $R$. By the lifting criterion, there are no sections $M\to\widetilde{M}$, so the $R$-module of sections is isomorphic to $\{r\in R: r=-r\}$, and again 3.27 gives the result.

Comment: Several questions: 
1. (a) says 'when $M$ is $R$ orientable', not 'when $M$ is orientable'. It could be that $M$ is nonorientable but $R$ orientable, what then? 
2. Sure, that might show the $R$ module of sections is $R$, but that's not what part (a) says, it says the map $H_n(M;R) \rightarrow H_n(M|x;R)$ is an isomorphism $\forall x \in M$. How can we connect the $R$ orientation to this?